# not getting data into mysql from java

Tags: java, mysql

I'm not getting data into mysql

```
    void connectionDB() {
        try {
            Class.forName(fileReader.getdriver());
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://"+ fileReader.gethost() + ":" + fileReader.getDBport() +"/" + fileReader.getdbname();
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, fileReader.getusername(),fileReader.getpasswd());
         } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            se.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
public void snmp_mysql(String ipv6Address, String[] resString) {
try {
    stat = conn.createStatement();
    String sql =
        ("INSERT INTO Statistics3 VALUES ('" + ipv6Address + "','"
            + dateTime.trim() + "'," + battpercent + ")");
    stat.executeUpdate(sql);
    stat.close();

    System.out.println("updating");
 } catch (SQLException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
             System.out.println("SQL statement is not executed!");
         }
    }
```

The code is not showing any error and it is showing Empty set (0.01 sec) in MySQL. Previously it worked properly and got the output. I didn't make any changes. I do not know why its not working.
I have taken another class in another project and added some columns to the existing table Statistics3,and used mysql for that class.I didnt make any changes in this class.That doesn't effect mysql know 
While i'm running the project,i'm getting these errors in the middle of the output

```
java.sql.SQLException: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1073)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3597)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3529)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1990)
```

Comment: Have you called `stat.executeUpdate()`?

Comment: Show your code how you execute your sql query string that you created.

Comment: This code doesn't show an insert. It shows the creation of a connection and a statement, then an assignment of an SQL command to a String variable.

Comment: Can you post some more code??

Comment: Have your Loaded the Driver class...

Comment: I have edited the code.I have taken  another class in another project and added some columns lo the existing table Statistics3,and used mysql for that class.I didnt make any changes in this class.That doesn't effect mysql know

Comment: I have used import java.sql.*;

Comment: Give this code inside try catch and post your stack-trace here it will help us to find the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can explicitly specify the column into which you want to insert data.. As you can see, you can also skip some column..

```
String sql =
    "INSERT INTO Statistics3 (column1, column2, column4) VALUES ('" + ipv6Address
                            + "','" + dateTime.trim() + "'," + battpercent + ")";
```

`column1`, `column2`, and `column4` are columns corresponding to your values - `ipv6Address`, `datetime`, and `battpercent`.. in your table..

So, if you have inserted a column - `column3` , then you can just skip it.. It will get the default value as you have set..

Comment: From your stack trace it seems like you are inserting `more` or `less` value than the number of columns in the table..

Comment: @user1659213 .. What is your table structure??

Comment: i have changed the columns in the mysql,Statistics3 table.before there used to be 9 columns and i have added 4 columns.now total they are 11

Comment: Will adding the columns effect this class.If so,how to change

Comment: @user1659213 you can explicitly specify, what column are you inserting values into.. See my updated post..

Comment: now,do i need to mention the columns where i want to insert the value.ie.,Wherever i am using Statistics3 there i have specift columns also know

Comment: @user1659213.. If you are not inserting in all the columns, then yes you need to do that..

Comment: or I can put null for the columns i dont use now know.I have tried with giving columns.But i didnt get it

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17538/discussion-between-rohit-jain-and-user1659213)

Answer (score 0):

> added some columns to the existing table Statistics3

There is your problem. Number of values does not match with number of columns present.

You should use version of SQL statement

```
 insert into table (col1,col2) values (val1,val2)
```

Comment: You should use version of SQL statement

 insert into table (col1,col2) values (val1,val2) ,i didnt understand it.

Comment: you should specify column names for which you are inserting values so that insert will happen for those particular columns.

Answer (score 0):

The values given in the insert query doesn't match with the columns in the DB. Make sure that you have values for all the columns(in your table) in your query.